# Linux "Default Permissions" for Future Files recursively?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, rhel

I have a Cache folder which needs `777` for everything inside. For existing ones, and the any newly/future created files, folders, sub-folders, etc.

Lets say: `/var/www/html/cache`

So how to do it in Linux (or RHEL) please?

Answer (score 2):

You should running the following command in a `/var/www/html/cache`

```
umask 000
```

This subtracts `000` from the system defaults to give a default access permission for your files of `666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) and for your directories of `777` (`rwxrwxrwx`).

[umask manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)

Comment: `000`? Sorry i don't know but is it really `000`, for what i need is `777`?